# Redirect other project page under same solution

Tags: asp.net

I have a web application. In my application there are 7 projects under same solution.
Now how I will redirect Project A page-1 to Project B page-1.

I have tried with

```
Response.Redirect("http://localhost:20431/Admin/Admin_Home.aspx");
```

But its not working please someone help me.

Thanks
Gulrej

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirection Not Working Classic Asp Site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14453115/redirection-not-working-classic-asp-site)

Comment: How do you access the applications from the browser? are they under the same domain but different folder like www.domain.com/app1 www.domain.com/app2? or are they in different domains?

Comment: My application is not hosted yet...I have created a solution, and for each module I have created different different project.

Comment: This doesn't sound like `Classic ASP` it sounds like `ASP.NET`.

Answer (score 0):

the redirect method knows the difference between absolute and relative paths. so if the "other page" is within the same domain use a relative path. If it's not within the same domain use an absolute path.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more. I am very new to ASP.net

Comment: start with http://w3schools.com/ and http://www.asp.net/mvc you can also search for content on  "understanding http"